# Two Circles On Screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I keep seeing these two circles appear on my screen... my mouse cursor flickers when they appear. They go away after I use my mouse for a bit. I'm not sure if my touch screen is broke or its some setting

Dell latitude 5285

[image]

Comment: Its a software feature, nothing broken. Try pressing them. I bet its something for your touch screen.

Comment: Thats just on google chrome that screen, but its the whole desktop it takes over - If it is a software feature how is it enabled/disabled?

Comment: Please click on `edit` above and to the left and advise the make and model of your PC.

Comment: updated with model number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your computer is a convertible laptop and it has a touch screen. Is your glass cracked at all? When I repair broken touch screen laptops, often the screen "touches itself" if it is cracked or bent. This can be very annoying.

Windows will show touch spots where it experiences a touch. It helps give the user feedback that the OS has received touch input. This sounds like your issue.

If the glass is slightly cracked and you do not want to use the touch screen or if it becomes a problem to use your computer, you can disable it. See this for more information: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-touch-screen-windows-10

Comment: No cracks, but this has solved the issue - maybe something behind the glass